# emasc temp file cleanup

Tags: emacs

When I edit files with emacs, emacs creates a file with the same name, but with a tilde on the end:

> notes.txt~

When I save my changes and exit emacs, it doesn't remove the temp file.  Is there a setting I can make in the .emacs that forces it to delete temp files so that it stops cluttering my directories?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Emacs calls these backup files (as opposed to temporary files starting with #).  To not create these, add

```
(setq make-backup-files nil)
```

to your .emacs

Answer (score 1):

What KeithB said, or put your files into version control.